# Vue changing variable value on receiveing data from backend Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

i hope you are all doing ok.

I have a weird problem that i just can't find a way to solve and the worst part I don't even know how to start looking for this problem over the internet.
Here's the case:
I make a DB request with the code below in Laravel:

```
public function previsao(){
    $dados = [];
    $tempoEntrega = 0;
    $tempoTroca = 0;
    $sugestaoCompra = 0;
    $frequencia = 0;
    $qnt = 0;
    $qntI = 0;
    $qntR = 0;

    $todosOsDados = $this->TecManutencaoEstoquePecaRegM
        ->join('tec_manutencao_pecas', 'tec_manutencao_estoque_peca_regs.pecaId', 'tec_manutencao_pecas.id')
        ->where('dataComp', '!=', null)
        ->get();

    foreach ($todosOsDados as $todId) {
        $toIds[] = $todId->pecaId;
    }

    $idsUnicos = array_unique($toIds);
    foreach ($idsUnicos as $idu) {
        $ids[] = $idu;
    }

    foreach ($ids as $id) {
        $peca = $this->TecManutencaoPecasM
            ->select('peca')
            ->where('id', $id)
            ->first();

        $entrega = $this->TecManutencaoEstoquePecaRegM
            ->join('tec_manutencao_pecas', 'tec_manutencao_estoque_peca_regs.pecaId', 'tec_manutencao_pecas.id')
            ->where('dataComp', '!=', null)
            ->where('pecaId', $id)
            ->where('mov', 'i')
            ->select('data', 'dataComp', 'qnt', 'est_min')
            ->get();

        foreach ($entrega as $e) {
            $tempoEntrega += (Carbon::parse($e->data)->diffInDays(Carbon::parse($e->dataComp)));
            $estMin = $e->est_min; 
            $qntI += $e->qnt; 
        }

        $qntRetirada = $this->TecManutencaoEstoquePecaRegM
            ->join('tec_manutencao_pecas', 'tec_manutencao_estoque_peca_regs.pecaId', 'tec_manutencao_pecas.id')
            ->where('dataComp', '!=', null)
            ->where('pecaId', $id)
            ->where('mov', 'r')
            ->select('qnt')
            ->get();

        foreach ($qntRetirada as $qr) {                    
            $qntR += $qr->qnt;
        }

        $qnt = $qntI - $qntR;

        $uso = $this->TecManutencaoEstoquePecaRegM
            ->where('pecaId', $id)
            ->where('mov', 'r')
            ->select('data')
            ->get();

        foreach ($uso as $u) {
            $ultimaEntrega = $this->TecManutencaoEstoquePecaRegM
                ->join('tec_manutencao_pecas', 'tec_manutencao_estoque_peca_regs.pecaId', 'tec_manutencao_pecas.id')
                ->where('pecaId', $id)
                ->where('mov', 'i')
                ->where('data', '<=', $u->data)
                ->select('data')
                ->orderBy('data', 'DESC')
                ->first();
            
            $tempoTroca += (Carbon::parse($u->data)->diffInDays(Carbon::parse($ultimaEntrega->data)));

            $ultimaTroca = $u->data;
        }

        $frequencia = count($entrega);

        $sugestaoCompra = round(($tempoTroca * ($tempoEntrega + $frequencia)) - ($qnt - $estMin));

        $tempoTrocaMedio = count($uso) == 0 ? $tempoTroca : round($tempoTroca / count($uso));

        $tempoAteEstminAcabar = $qnt * $tempoTrocaMedio;

        $dataProxComp = $tempoAteEstminAcabar - round($tempoEntrega / count($entrega));

        $diasTroca = $tempoTroca <= 0 ? round($tempoEntrega / count($entrega)) : $dataProxComp;

        $dados[] = [
            'id' => $id,
            'peca' => $peca->peca,
            'tempoEntrega' => $tempoEntrega <= 0 ? $tempoEntrega : round($tempoEntrega / count($entrega)),
            'tempoTroca' => $tempoTroca <= 0 ? $tempoTroca : round($tempoTroca / count($uso)),
            'qntProxComp' => $sugestaoCompra,
            //'dataProxComp' => date('d/m/Y', strtotime($ultimaTroca.'+'.$diasTroca.' days')),
            'dataProxComp' => $ultimaTroca == 0 || $ultimaTroca == null ? 
                date('d/m/Y', strtotime($ultimaEntrega->data.'+'.$diasTroca.' days')) : 
                date('d/m/Y', strtotime($ultimaTroca.'+'.$diasTroca.' days')),
            'qnt' => $qnt,
            'estMin' => $estMin
        ];

        $tempoEntrega = 0;
        $tempoTroca = 0;
        $sugestaoCompra = 0;
        $frequencia = 0;
        $qnt = 0;
        $qntI = 0;
        $qntR = 0;
    }

    //dd($dados);

    return $dados;     
}
```

This code returns what I've expected:

[image: Return from the backEnd]

Then a get this return with Vue like this:

```
methods: {
    getPredictions(){
        axios.get(this.rotagetprevisoes, this.dadosIniciais).then(res => {
            this.dadosIniciais = res.data
            console.log(res.data)
        })
    },
    rowClass(filtered, type){
        if (!filtered) return
        if (filtered.estMin < filtered.qnt) return 'table-success'
        if (filtered.estMin = filtered.qnt) return 'table-warning'
        if (filtered.estMin > filtered.qnt) return 'table-danger'
    },
    openRepModal(){
        this.$root.$emit('bv::show::modal', 'gerRelPrev', '#btnShow')
    },
    sugModal(item){
        if(item.qntProxComp >= 0){
            this.qntSuges = item.qntProxComp
            this.acimaEstMin = 'n'
        } else {
            this.qntSuges = Math.abs(item.qntProxComp)
            this.acimaEstMin = 's'
        }
        this.dataSuges = item.dataProxComp
        this.$root.$emit('bv::show::modal', 'adminSugestao', '#btnShow')
    }
},
```

But what I got here is:

[image: Vue Console Log]

Note that the "*estMin*" has different values when is sent and when is received, the weirdest part is that it only goes from Laravel to Vue, nothing in the middle.
I already try changing a lot of parts of my code, doing it all over again but, ended up with the same result, try searching for something related over the internet but no succeed.
This field "*estMin*" is the only one affected and, it's not even a calculated field, it's only the data that I get from DB.
I simply don't understand why "*estMin*" comes from Laravel with the values that I expect and arrive in Vue with a different value.
One more thing, this is an array of objects, only pick one example to show you guys.
Can someone help me please?

Comment: You are assigning a value to `$estMin` here: `$estMin = $e->est_min;`. Did you mean to sum the values, as in: `$estMin += $e->est_min;`?

Comment: Maybe a caching issue?

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for answering, @DigitalDrifter, i didn't mean to sum, estMin is a unique value that I get from DB, don't need to sum.

Comment: @jgauffin, I already clear everything that I could on Laravel and Vue, cache, route, config, view etc...
It is just weird or I'm missing something.

Comment: Have you tried to change the request to a POST?

Comment: Hi @jgauffin, thanks for helping me, i haven't try this yet but, since it's a GET request, why changing to POST would fix?

Comment: Because POST requests are never cached in web servers or frameworks.

Comment: I didn't know about this, thank's for the explanation @jgauffin, but still not working...

Answer (score 0):

thanks for trying to help me, i just figure what I was doing wrong and, it was stupid.
I've edited the question so you guys can have a better understand:
In the rowClass method, I have this line:

```
if (filtered.estMin = filtered.qnt) return 'table-warning'
```

I didn't notice the '=' sign, that's why the estMin was aways with a different value so, I change the '=' sign for '===' and the problems were solved:

```
if (filtered.estMin === filtered.qnt) return 'table-warning'
```

Honestly, I don't understand why exactly this method can be interfering with the other but, it is working.

Again, thank you all that have tried to help me.